# drawing a specific number of rects (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a specific number of rectangles with different widths, next to each other. When any rectangle hits the maximum width of my svg element (e.g. 500), it should continue in the next line. Is it possible to solve this in a simple way?

[Output - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86ipi.png)
This is, what I got so far. The problem is, firebug shows, that my last width (570) is to big for my svg.

```
<script>
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var rectHeight = 20;
var xPos = 0;
var xWidthOld = 0;
var rectSpace = 0.5;
var dataArray = [20, 78, 40, 60, 570];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

rects = d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
.data(dataArray)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("width", function(d) { return d; })
.attr("height", rectHeight)
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
return getPos(d, i);
});


function getPos(rectWidth, index) {
if(index != 0)
xPos = xPos + xWidthOld + rectSpace;

xWidthOld = rectWidth;
return xPos;
}
</script>
```

EDIT - New Picture - [Continue new Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yutjP.png)

Comment: Do you have an example close to what you want ? Do you have to use SVG ?

Comment: At the end it should work like an interactive treemap, but all rectangles should have the same hight, only the width shall be different. No i dont have to, but I thought its good to use it.

Comment: It already exists in D3, why do you want to do it yourself ? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582

Comment: Is it possible to draw the same visualisation as you can see in my picture (Edit-1) with it?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @endkugelfang You mean you want to draw on one line only ?

Comment: No, the part of my last rect which exceeds the width of my svg should continue in the next line

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't care for your layout to be a full square, you just want it to just a line when it's too long ?

Comment: Every data of my array represents a rectangle. There could be much more than five as in my example. The width of these rectangles is the datasize. I just want to put every data next to each other and if there isn't enough space in one line (like in my example) to continue in the next line, under the line before (the first in my example). This procedure shall end when every data is represented through a rectangle....If my SVG is 500x500 or 1200x600 doesnt matter. Do you understand my approach? :)

Comment: @Elfayer just have a look at my new uploaded picture :)

Comment: Should it support overflow ? I made it so that if it goes outside, it jumps the line.

Comment: I'll have to come back to you later, I don't have time right now ;)

Comment: I updated my answer with a new solution that manages the overflow as you asked, let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used two different algorithms. The first is calculating the position of each node on D3 cycle, the second is calculating the positions in advance via `initData` function.

Here is what I have:

### When it overflows, it jumps a line

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var rectHeight = 20;
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
var rectSpace = 0.5;
var dataArray = [20, 78, 40, 60, 370, 42];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

rects = d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataArray)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("height", rectHeight)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return getPosX(d, i);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return getPosY(d, i);
  });

// Calculate PosX
function getPosX(rectWidth, index) {
  // If rect goes out of the SVG, restart at posX = 0
  if (posX + rectWidth > width) {
    posX = 0;
  }
  newPosX = posX; // Return this position
  posX += rectWidth + 1; // prepare position for next node
  return newPosX;
}

// Calculate PosY
function getPosY(rectWidth, index) {
  // reset posX at first calculation of posY
  if (index == 0) {
    posX = 0;
  }
  // If rect goes out of the SVG increment Y position of rect
  if (posX + rectWidth > width) {
    posY += rectHeight + 1;
    posX = 0;
  }
  posX += rectWidth + 1; // Calculate position for next node
  return posY;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fgtn0tyb/)

### When it overflows, the node is cut and the rest is added to a new line

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var rectHeight = 20;
var rectSpace = 0.5;
var dataArray = [20, 78, 40, 60, 1370, 42];
var nodes = [];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

rects = d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
  .data(initData(dataArray))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .attr("height", rectHeight)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return d.y;
  });

// Build displayed data below
function initData(data) {
  var posX = 0;
  var posY = 0;

  // Claculate position of each node
  for (var i in data) {
    var node = addNode(data[i], posX, posY);

    // If there is an overflow
    if (node.x + node.value > width) {
      var overflowValue = node.x + node.value - width;

      // Add nodes until there is no more overflow
      while (overflowValue > 0) {
        // Update current node value
        node.value = width - node.x;
        // Calculate new node posX and posY
        posX = 0;
        posY += rectHeight + 1;
        node = addNode(overflowValue, posX, posY);
        // Claculate new overflow
        overflowValue = node.x + node.value - width;
      }
    }
    posX += node.value + 1;
  }

  return nodes;
}

function addNode(value, x, y) {
  var newNode = {
    value: value,
    x: x,
    y: y
  };

  nodes.push(newNode);

  return newNode;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d13cpp58/)